# How to pass value from date range picker to SQL?

Tags: php, postgresql, daterangepicker

I faced two problems here:

(A) How do I pass the value of start date and end date from this ***http://www.daterangepicker.com/#example4*** into query *select *  from table_name where date between '**start date**' and '**end date'***

(B) My data consists of date within ***2018/04/11 to 2018/04/13***，which means it also include these two dates.  How to ensure the selected date range can be displayed in the query result?

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: @Joseph_J, I'm using http://www.daterangepicker.com/#example4

Answer (score 1):

first of all, sql stores them using different format (by default) so you will have to convert it, maybe by using `strtotime()` and `date()` combination to get the wanted SQL format.

then you can use BETWEEN WHERE clause to filter values like:
`WHERE created_at BETWEEN 2018-04-11 AND 2018-04-13`

Answer (score 1):

First extract the dates via explode:

```
$dates = explode(" to ", $datesFromDatepicker);
```

Then create the start and end date:

```
$start= DateTime::createFromFormat('Y/m/d', $dates[0]);
$end= DateTime::createFromFormat('Y/m/d', $dates[1]);
```

In your query use:

```
$start->format("Y-m-d");
$end->format("Y-m-d");
```

Comment: any reason to use explode for php?

Comment: because the author said the range is in that "string" format, so it's easiest getting this by explode. IMHO, this is good way to get those two values out.